# Tuning 1D CNN Prediction Model Using Bayesian Optimization (bayes_opt Library) - Handling Discrete and Integer Parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, bayesian

I am currently working on a 1D CNN-based prediction model and wish to optimize its performance by tuning hyperparameters using Bayesian optimization. I plan to utilize the bayes_opt library to facilitate this process efficiently. However, I encountered a couple of questions while setting up the optimization procedure.

1. Discrete Values for Hyperparameter:
   Is there a way to use these discrete values in the Bayesian optimization search space?
   example:
   bounds = {'filters': (16,32,64)}
   I noticed that bayes_opt supports continuous search spaces, but I'm unsure how to handle
   discrete values for a hyperparameter.
2. Integer Values for Hyperparameters:
   In my 1D CNN architecture, I have hyperparameters like the number of neurons and the number of hidden layers, which must be integers. While applying Bayesian optimization, I tried converting the continuous values to integers inside the objective function, using filters = int(filters). However, this approach does not work.

Could someone kindly guide me on how to correctly handle discrete and integer-valued hyperparameters within the Bayesian optimization process for my 1D CNN prediction model? Any insights or code examples demonstrating the proper implementation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!